# App crashing on lpConfigStringForKey with Linphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, linphone, linphone-sdk

I have an iOS voip app that utilizes the Linphone library. Previously the app was running successfully but I have just upgraded the linphone frameworks and files: LinphoneManager.h/.m and Utils.h/.m from [linphone-iphone](https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-iphone).

After adding the updated frameworks from a new version of the linphone-sdk and updating LinphoneManager.h/m I am running into a crash on startup of the application. The crash occurs once the app hits

```
lp_config_get_string(_configDb, [section UTF8String], [key UTF8String], NULL);
```

in lpConfigStringForKey().

I have tried removing and readding the frameworks and checking the LinphoneManager.h/.m code but I have not come across a solution nor have I found any instances similar to mine in the linphone-iphone issues.

The crash occurs as it hits the following block of code

```
- (NSString *)lpConfigStringForKey:(NSString *)key inSection:(NSString *)section withDefault:(NSString *)defaultValue {
    if (!key) {
        return defaultValue;
    }
    const char *value = lp_config_get_string(_configDb, [section UTF8String], [key UTF8String], NULL);
    return value ? [NSString stringWithUTF8String:value] : defaultValue;
}
```

This is a standard function in LinphoneManager.m that I have not modified.

Specifically, the crash comes from this function in the linphone framework:

```
lp_config_get_string(_configDb, [section UTF8String], [key UTF8String], NULL);
```

I have logged the key, section and defaultValue variables when the app crashes. They are:

```
2019-07-11 10:58:51.033849-0500 myApp[15512:511705] KEY: debugenable_preference
2019-07-11 10:58:51.033964-0500 myApp[15512:511705] SECTION: app
2019-07-11 10:58:51.034040-0500 myApp[15512:511705] DEFAULT: (null)
```

The header comments for the linphone_config_get_string which is what lp_config_get_string points to are the following:

```
/**
 * Retrieves a configuration item as a string, given its section, key, and default value.
 *
 * The default value string is returned if the config item isn't found.
**/
LINPHONE_PUBLIC const char *linphone_config_get_string(const LinphoneConfig *lpconfig, const char *section, const char *key, const char *default_string);
```

Here is a screenshot of the error and crash:
[Crash stack trace and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkWzb.jpg)

I figure I am missing something when adding the frameworks but I haven't been able to find it yet.

- Note - If I comment out the lp_config_get_string call then when the app gets to the next lp_config function call it crashes there. So it looks like it has something to do with the linphone.framework and the lp_config module but I have not found the solution yet.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. The following was missing from the init function:

```
    [self renameDefaultSettings];
    [self copyDefaultSettings];
    [self overrideDefaultSettings];
```

Which was causing some issues with the lp_config